# How to close a TcpClient

Tags: .net, tcpclient, .net-core

There is no `TcpClient.Close()` method in .Net Core/.Net Standard.
[image]

How do I close the client?

Comment: Use Dispose() instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Hans Passant. Dispose() does exist, and maybe the only way to close, but somehow it feels like not a good way. The .net core API does change a lot at the method/member level, migration from .Net Framework might be a tough work.

Comment: Little point in nagging me about it, file complaints [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues).  Click the New Issue button.

Comment: If you're bothered that much write yourself an extension method that calls `Dispose` internally - that is what the [desktop .NET version](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,446) does as well. Should there ever be a `TcpClient.Close` method in .NET core, then this will be picked up instead of your extension method (given a recompile).

Comment: Close is a legacy API anyway. The standard method is Dispose. This is a .NET Framework design bug, there should only be one API.

Answer (score 2):

As @HansPassant said, `Dispose()` is the way to go.

A `using` block will automatically dispose the client:

```
using (client)
{
    //...
}
```

Or, you can add a method to your class:

```
public void Close()
{
    client?.Dispose();
}
```

An even better solution would be to make your class that consumes `TcpClient` implement `IDisposable` as well.